# MPDI journal, add line numbers

Tags: templates, mdpi

I am using the mdpi template on overleaf to write an article.

I am using the following line in the preamble:
%=================================================================
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi}

As I am using "submit" it shall show the line numbers, however, this is not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that MDPI is a predatory publisher that will print anything for money: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDPI#Evaluation_and_controversies